# Random repeating elements in an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using `_.sample` in underscore.js to pull random elements from an array.

I have less elements in the source list than the amount I want to sample, but it's maxing out at 4 (the length of the source).

What are some other options for returning 17 random elements (with repeats, obviously) from 4 options in an array? I'm seeing a lot on removing the repeats but can't figure out what allows for them to repeat.

```
let dots = _.sample([component 1, component 2, component 3, component 4], 17);
```

Comment: Are you saying that it's only returning 4 elements when you asked for 17?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I'm thinking I probably won't be able to use the random selector in underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get random numbers from 0 to 3 (you can use underscores's [_.random](https://underscorejs.org/docs/modules/random.html)), and use them as index to get elements from you components array.

```
var components = [component1, component2, component3, component4]
var dots = []
for (var i = 0; i < 17; ++i) dots.push(components[_.random(3)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`let dots = _.sample(Array.from({length: 5}).fill([component 1, component 2, component 3, component 4]).flat(), 17)`

Comment: Hi There, try explaining your approach for people to better understand your solution.